# Sqoop Job scheduling with crontab

Tags: cron, sqoop

How do we run Sqoop jobs by keeping them in a shell script, and calling them on a particular frequency through crontab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these steps to execute the job via `cron`.

1) Create a script file and type the Sqoop command in it.

```
vim my_sqoop_job.sh
```

2) Make the script executable.

```
chmod 755 my_sqoop_job.sh
```

3) Edit crontab.

```
crontab -e
```

4) Add the path and job (below example runs every 30 min)

*(Ensure the PATH contains the location for Sqoop's bin directory)*

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client/bin            
*/30 * * * * /location/of/my_sqoop_job.sh >> /location/of/logs/my_sqoop_job_run.log 2>&1
```

The job will run every 30 minutes and logs will be available in `my_sqoop_job_run.log`